# How to change controls layout in child user controls

Tags: c#, user-controls, parent-child

I have a user control implemented for a windows application. I have derived this user control and created one more child user control. But the problem is I am not able to change the control layout in child user control, being everything is locked.

How to change the layout of controls in child user control keeping the functionality same as parent user control ?

*If I change the modifiers of controls in parent control to public, I can change the layout. But I am not sure if it is a correct way or not.*

Thanks,

Vijay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should try keeping the controls as protected instead of public.

Comment: But then how to change the layout of child user control ?